# NextJS: static site generation + client-side filtering?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a page that shows a bunch of images. This page should support images filtering by some property (let's say, location). Location can be passed in the URL (https://coolsite.com?location=1). Later on I'll add some kind of filter to this page, which also can change location. This page is going to be a main page of my site, and data is not changing frequently. Obvious idea is to pre-render it statically (implement getStaticProps).

But with this approach - is it possible to implement client-side filtering (by value in URL and by changing filter)?

It seems like it's not possible, and two options would be:

1. implement getStaticProps and getStaticPaths, then my pages will become: index page (https://coolsite.com) when location is not specified and pages for specific locations https://coolsite.com/location/1, https://coolsite.com/location/2 etc.)
2. implement server-side rendering + client-side filtering

Can anyone please suggest what is the best approach for this in NextJs?